# Bootstrap Fullcalendar Storing Object - i add/modify an object at chrome but after i refresh the calendar the changes gone away

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

How Store the Object, until i decide modify or delete. i make the change thru the web browser like dragging in the object or click in the calendar but after i refresh the page, goes back to default. Boostrap. thanks for the help

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------c ------------------*/

        $('#external-events div.external-event2').each(function () {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });






        });







        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------c ------------------*/

        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });






        });


        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                // calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },




            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {


                var title = prompt('Rename Event Title:');

                calEvent.title = title;
                // copiedEventObject.title = title;
                alert('Altered Event : ' + calEvent.title);


                // change the border color just for fun
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

            },







            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');


                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                //    copiedEventObject.title = 'abc';     //<<<Change the title



                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

            }
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store events in the database with an `AJAX` request. And fetch that from the same, on your `drop:function();` try bellow code:

```
drop: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, ui) { // this function is called when something is dropped
    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

    //cvalculate endTime using duration of event
    var endTime = date.getTime() + (copiedEventObject.duration*60000);

   //function to store event data to db.
   saveEventData(date, allDay, copiedEventObject, endTime, copiedEventObject.duration);
}
```

**saveEventData function**

```
 //function to save events when droped external events
function saveEventData(start, allday, copiedEventObject, endTime, duration) {
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: ''//url to your code,
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            data: {'start':start, 'allday': allday, 'end': endTime, 'additional_info':copiedEventObject},
            success: function (response) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
            }
        });
}
```

And Now try adding `events: ''//url to your json feed` to your calendar [Check docs here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) OR you can use another method `events` as array [docs here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/)